# Elasticsearch performance degradation after migration to es 5

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

We have recently migrated our es clusters from 1.4 to 5.4 and seeing degradation in the performance.

```
 {
"from": 0,
"size": 100,
"query": {
"constant_score": {
"filter": {
"bool": {
"must": [
{
"term": {
"entityType": {
"value": "PAID_INITIATIVE"
}
}
}
]
}
}
}
}
}
```

`

JVM : Java 8
Hardware is same for both the clusters
We aren't using both the cluster for any other queries except for load testing

Issue becomes deep when we query for 100k docs (size : 100k)

We have a use case, where we need to filter 100k docs
I have tested with both LZ4 and best_compression in es 5 cluster. Performance is bad in both cases

```
For 100k docs
Es 1.4 : ~2s
ES 5.4 : ~3.5s (LZ4)
ES 5.4 : ~ 5s (best_compression)
```

I have checked the hot threads

Most of the threads are stuck at decompression

100.2% (501ms out of 500ms) cpu usage by thread 'elasticsearch[es-data-nqa-spr_nqa_elasticsearch-5.4-1-7-1c][[transport_server_worker.default]][T#12]'
7/10 snapshots sharing following 52 elements

```
java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes(Native Method)
java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:259)
org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressionMode$DeflateDecompressor.decompress(CompressionMode.java:224)
org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsReader$BlockState.document(CompressingStoredFieldsReader.java:560)
org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsReader.document(CompressingStoredFieldsReader.java:576)
org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsReader.visitDocument(CompressingStoredFieldsReader.java:583)
org.apache.lucene.index.CodecReader.document(CodecReader.java:88)
org.apache.lucene.index.FilterLeafReader.document(FilterLeafReader.java:411)
org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.FetchPhase.loadStoredFields(FetchPhase.java:347)
```

I just need the id from the documents, even when I try with stored_fields : ["id"], it still decompresses the documents.

Any insights on this would be highly appreciated

Thanks,
Nitish

Comment: Hey Nitish, did you ever figured out the problem or find a solution ?

Comment: It seems like, there is no way to bypass the decompression. Elasticsearch will always decompress the documents while returning back the response